# Envio de Amizade

Tags: php

Olá! Estou criando um sistema tipo rede social. Porém travei na parte de enviar solicitação de amizade. Criei as tabelas de usuário e de amizade, mas não estou conseguindo inserir. Fica dizendo que deu erro na linha da query. Parece que o erro é na hora de inserir na tabela.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

HTML:

```
<form method="POST">
  <h2><?php echo $saber["nome"]; ?></h2><br/>
  <?php
    $amigos = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM amizades WHERE de='$login_cookie' AND para='$email' OR para='$login_cookie' AND de='$email'");
    $amigoss = mysqli_fetch_assoc($amigos);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($amigos)>=1 AND $amigoss["aceite"]=="sim") {
      echo '<input type="submit" value="Remover amigo" name="remover"><input type="submit" name="denunciar" value="Denunciar">';
    }elseif (mysqli_num_rows($amigos)>=1 AND $amigoss["aceite"]=="nao" AND $amigoss["de"]==$login_cookie){
      echo '<input type="submit" value="Cancelar pedido" name="cancelar"><input type="submit" name="denunciar" value="Denunciar">';
    }else{
      echo '<input type="submit" value="Adicionar amigo" name="add"><input type="submit" name="denunciar" value="Denunciar">';
    }
  ?>
  </form>
```

PHP

```
if (isset($_POST['add'])) {
  add();
}

function add(){
  $login_cookie = $_COOKIE['login'];
  if (!isset($login_cookie)) {
    header("Location: login.php");
  }
  $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","rede");
  $id = $_GET['id'];
  $saberr = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE id='$id'");
  $saber = mysqli_fetch_assoc($saberr);
  $email = $saber['email'];
  $data = date("Y/m/d");

  $ins = "INSERT INTO amizades (de, para, data) VALUES ('".$login_cookie."','".$email."','".$data."')";
    $conf = mysqli_query($con, $ins) or die(mysqli_error());

  if($conf) {
    header("Location: profile.php?id=".$id);
  }else{
    echo "<h3>Erro ao enviar pedido...</h3>";
  }
}
```

Comment: Coloque sua mensagem de erro.

Comment: Coloque o erro, fica dificil sem

Comment: http://prntscr.com/gfy0bi

Comment: Troque a foto por texto.

Comment: Field 'id' doesn't have a default value

Comment: Consegui eu n criei o id int primary key auto_increment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Voce precisa passar o link de conexão com o banco para a função de erro do mysql

```
$conf = mysqli_query($con, $ins) or die(mysqli_error($con));
```

Comment: Apareceu isso aqui: Field 'id' doesn't have a default value

Comment: Consegui eu n criei o id int primary key auto_increment.

Comment: Que bom que deu certo.